# C# How do I find an unique value (if any) in multiple list

Tags: c#, linq

Let’s say I’m having three `List<int>` with the following values:

1st contains 1,2,3,4

2nd contains 1,3

3th contains 1,3,4

How (most likely using LINQ?) would I be able to get value 2, because 2 only appears one time in all three lists.

Comment: What results did you get? Invalid item, error? Use `Enumerable.Intersect` and next time please post your code

Comment: What you tried so far? Can you show us minimal reproducible example? Where did you stuck? What was the error (if any)?

Comment: if a list contains `1, 3, 5, 5` but no other list contains a `5`, should it be included in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one IEnumerable that contains all elements via `Concat` and then use `GroupBy` to check which elements in this IEnumerable occurs only one time:

```
var first = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4};
var second = new List<int> { 1, 3};
var third= new List<int> { 1, 3, 4};

var single = first.Concat(second).Concat(third).GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the duplicates in each lists and concate them.

Then, you can group by and filter only elements that have a `.Count() == 1` :

```
var lst1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var lst2 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 5 }; // added duplicate 5 in that list
var lst3 = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4 };
var result = lst1.Distinct()
                 .Concat(lst2.Distinct())
                 .Concat(lst3.Distinct())
                 .GroupBy(elem => elem)
                 .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                 .Select(g => g.Key);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result)); // 2, 5
```

[Try it yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqAynv)